# ServletWrapper uncaught exception after upgrade to WAS 8

Tags: java, websphere, apache-axis

Upgraded from `RAD 7.5` > `RAD 8.5` & `WAS 7` > `WAS 8`. Made jar & JRE reference changes, got past all the hard compile/build errors and am able to start the server w/o error and am able to get to my app's 1st page. Upon entry of some fields and clicking submit, I get the error - any ideas?

```
ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet action: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org/w3c/dom/Node.lookupNamespaceURI(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.utils.NodeNamespaceContext.getNamespaceURIDomLevel3(NodeNamespaceContext.java:92)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.utils.NodeNamespaceContext.getNamespaceURI(NodeNamespaceContext.java:84)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.getRefQName(SchemaBuilder.java:570)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSimpleContentExtension(SchemaBuilder.java:825)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSimpleContent(SchemaBuilder.java:735)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleComplexType(SchemaBuilder.java:670)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:205)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:121)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:512)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:385)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1892)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleImport(SchemaBuilder.java:1606)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:224)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:121)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:512)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:385)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1892)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1921)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleInclude(SchemaBuilder.java:1647)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:219)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:481)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder$1.run(WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.java:148)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder$1.run(WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.java:146)
at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:76)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.getXMLSchema(WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.java:145)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.copyExtensibleElements(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:2492)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.processTypes(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:420)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.processTypes(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:409)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:349)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.buildAxisServiceFromWSDL(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:977)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.setupAxisService(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:776)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:275)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.updateEndpointDescription(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:534)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:382)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactory.java:180)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:513)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)
at com.usbank.soa.basecustomerservice_v_3_0.BaseCustomerService.getBaseCustomerServiceSOAP(BaseCustomerService.java:52)
at com.usbank.soa.basecustomerservice_v_3_0.BaseCustomerServiceRequest.sendRequest(BaseCustomerServiceRequest.java:38)
at com.usb.emailpref.action.emailaction.execute(emailaction.java:178)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3815)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
```

Because of various posts around the internet that talked about removing SAXParser* classes found in jaxp_1.1.1.jar (as those parsers are in the base WAS 8.5 jars), I removed them. But it still hasn't remedied the problem. As I walked thru my code, the error was being thrown when sending the SOAP message so it's entirely possible it is related to a parsing issue.

Does any one have additional thoughts on this?

Comment: I've since updated the jaxb from 1.0 to 2.2.3, tried changing class loader policy from parent first to parent last, disabling DisableIBMJAXWSEngine both in the MANIFEST.MF and in the server, and added to the generic JVM argument " -Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.MessageFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl". Can anyone hazard a idea???

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue??  I am having the same problem and it is driving me crazy!  The NodeNamespaceContext and Node classes should only be provided by WAS (those classes aren't anywhere in my EAR deployment), so I am very confused as to why NodeNamespaceContext would reference an older version of the Node class!

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet. I am in fact re-encountering this same error because the issue of upgrading to WAS v8.5 was dropped last year and have been put back working on it again. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Dan, I'm still encountering this issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately found that I needed to remove crimson_1.1.1.jar, xmlparser_3.3.02.jar, and xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar from the included jars. I also had to remove the parsers folder from jaxp_1.1.1.jar. These jars have since been superseded/replaced in the newer WAS v8.5 standard jars in which the XML formatting method interfaces (these methods at a minimum) have been altered causing the implementation to change. Same notation in the removal of parsers folder from jaxp_1.1.1.jar. Once removed, the error disappeared and my app now works in RAD 8.5 & WAS 8.5.5.5.

By the by since this is SOAP/WSDL/XML related, if you happen to encounter the following error - "CWPOL0040E: The client cannot establish how policy is configured for the service {http://soa.usbank.com/BaseCustomerService_V_3_0}BaseCustomerService because while processing the WSDL document attached to the service the following exception occurred com.ibm.ws.wspolicy.UnsupportedNamespaceException", you'll need to add the argument - “ -Dcom.ibm.ws.wspolicy.ignoreWSP12inPackagedWSDL=true" (there's a prefacing space before the hyphen) to the Generic JVM argument list. This error doesn't always happen but did in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Super old thread, but just wanted to add another perspective as I fought this same issue. For me, the crimson dependency was the primary culprit. After moving to WAS 8.5 and Java 8, I removed the following:

- crimson
- jaxp-api
- xml-apis (ensuring no transitive dependency)
- xercesImpl
- note: did not have a jaxp implementation jar to begin with